# Converting code from Java, Sage, etc

Tags: discussion

Is it ok to ask for some help in converting code from another programming language into *Mathematica* code? I can't find anywhere on the internet to get such help, and perhaps seeing code snippets converted would be beneficial to others looking to do the same. They'd be able to follow how each line was revised for *Mathematica*, and better understand both languages similarities and differences. I realize there's some selfishness in this request, but I'm unsure where to get help, and don't want to have to learn a complete other programming language, when I'm still trying to get the finer points of *Mathematica*.

Comment: [Closely related](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1141/4330)

Comment: In my opinion code in other languages should never be more than additional information for those familiar with that language. If the question is not answerable without reading and understanding that code, I consider it to be off-topic.

Comment: "They'd be able to follow how each line was revised for Mathematica" For most programs a line by line conversion is the worst approach. Although that's how language comparison benchmarks seem to be coded.

Comment: JLink makes the Java conversion rather simple, but Sage could certainly be tricky.

Comment: @William JLink doesn't convert the code tho, right? It just allows Java code to be run within Mathematica. I'm looking for actual Mathematica code that I can manipulate.

Comment: @Karsten7. I agree to some extent, but I personally asked for help with a math related problem both on Math.SE and Mathematica.SE. An answer on Math.SE included code in Java and Sage as those were all he knew. All I know is Mathematica. Mathematica.SE gave answers with code that works, but are much more memory and processor intensive as the math knowledge used to build the Java and Sage programs was much better. Thus, I'm looking for Mathematica code that doesn't just get me the same answer, but is based off the same math, thus knowledge of the Java/Sage code is necessary.

Comment: I've gone ahead and asked my question here: mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115726/code-conforming-to-math-in-java-sage-code . Perhaps use this as an example for further discussion of what's on- or off-topic for the site. I'm more than willing to go by what others agree to, just want to get an example of the type of question this meta post is about so a decision can be made.

Answer (score 10):

Personally, I don't like such questions and would prefer that they not be asked on this site. However, my impression is that I am very much in the minority -- perhaps a minority of one.

So I'll say that is OK to ask such questions if they are well focused. The foreign code should not be too long. Dumping a complete Java program onto the site and asking for a translation will probably not be popular.

Comment: Perhaps a tag dedicated to this? That way those who aren't interested can avoid these questions, and a description of what's acceptable and what's not can be put into the tag summary?

Comment: I can't imagine you're in the minority about this.